# Bootstrap Modals, combine Jquery and JS code in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I would have 3 questions concerning the JQuery syntax:

1) The modal is not showing up. This may be an operator (&&) problem? How do I get it right? It should show up only if the thing is valid.

2) How to combine submit prevent Default with valid classes? I have used that before but never combined with JQuery. I want the modal only to show when is_email is valid and when the InputEmail, InputMessage and InputName fields were filled out.

```
$('#submit').click(function(submit){
        if($('#InputEmail'&&'#InputMessage'&&'#InputName').val().length === 0)&& (is_email=="valid") {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        submit.preventDefault();
       }

    );
```

4) If I put the col-lg6, it will change size, however the documentation says that I have to add this:

```
$('.message-group').attr({
                class: 'has-success'
```

works but if I add col-lg6 form-group name-group it will change the size. Why is this?

My syntax is:

```
/*JQUERY FORM EFFECTS*/

/*$('#InputName').on('input', function() {
    var input=$(this);
    var is_name=input.val();
    if(is_name){input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");}
    else{input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");}
});  Can I comment that out? */

$('#InputEmail').on('input', function() {
    var input=$(this);
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    var is_email=re.test(input.val());
    if(is_email){
        input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");

                }
    else{
        input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
    }
});

/* Display please enter a name. */

$('#InputName').focusout(function(){
        if($('#InputName').val().length === 0) {
            $('.name-group .message-block').text('Please enter your name.');
            $('.name-group').attr({
                class: 'has-error'
            }); // end attr
        } else {
            $('.name-group .message-block').text('');
            $('.name-group').attr({
                class: 'has-success'
            }); //end attr
        }
    }); //end focus out

$('#InputMessage').focusout(function(){
        if($('#InputMessage').val().length === 0) {
            $('.message-group .message-block').text('Please enter your message.');
            $('.message-group').attr({
                class: 'has-error'
            }); // end attr
        } else {
            $('.message-group .message-block').text('');
            $('.message-group').attr({
                class: 'has-success'
            }); //end attr
        }
    }); //end focus out

$('#InputEmail').focusout(function(){
        if($('#InputEmail').val().length === 0) {
            $('.mail-group .email-block').text('Please enter your email.');
            $('.mail-group').attr({
                class: 'has-error'
            }); // end attr
        } else {
            $('.mail-group .email-block').text('');
            $('.mail-group').attr({
                class: 'has-success'
            }); //end attr
        }
    }); //end focus out

$('#submit').click(function(submit){
        if($('#InputEmail'&&'#InputMessage'&&'#InputName').val().length === 0)&& (is_email=="valid") {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        submit.preventDefault();
       }

    );
```

My form:

```
      <div class="form-group name-group">
        <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i>
          </span>
       </div>
       <span class="text-block"></span>
     </div>

      <div class="form-group mail-group">
        <label for="InputEmail">Your Email</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
        <span class="email-block"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group message-group">
        <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
        <div class="input-group"
>
          <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control" rows="5" required></textarea>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
        </div>
        <span class="message-block"></span>
      </div>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem on a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show your markup for your div with the id of myModal?

Also, are you looking for a multiselect? If so here is a link to jQuery's documentation on including multiple element queries in a single selector call: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Something more like:

```
    if($('#InputEmail,#InputMessage,#InputName').val().length === 0)
    {
        alert('not filled out');
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
```

Also, if that is a direct copy/paste, you are missing a closing parenthesis on your if statement:

```
    if($('#InputEmail'&&'#InputMessage'&&'#InputName').val().length === 0)&& (is_email=="valid"))
```

Also, could you please clarify what you are asking in your bootstrap .css question?

Comment: I want the modal to show up if all is valid, do I do that with the first or with the second part that you wrote? If I put in the first thing, it is not working, cause it will give me an alert once I open the html document. And it anyways says please fill out this field? What do you suggest? I am using a standard bootstrap modal that I defined in my HTML.

Comment: It would be the first statement. The second statement simply showed that there was a syntactical error.

Comment: I, personally, would attach a callback to the button that you will click to open the modal: $('#whatever_your_button_id_is').click(function () { /*insert validation code here, open modal if valid, display error if not*/});